# Check the signature algorithm of RDP certificate

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, sha, rdp

I received a Nessus warning of RDP as following,

```
The following certificates were part of the certificate chain sent by the remote host, but contain hashes that are considered to be weak.

|-Subject             : CN=PBVA01  
|-Signature Algorithm : SHA-1 With RSA Encryption
```

But I have check the certificate and the signature algorithm is SHA-256.

The warning received a few months ago and it may not be updated. I want to confirm what algorithm is using in RDP (SHA-1 or SHA-256), so what should I do?

OS: windows server 2012 r2

Comment: You need to Have the certificate reissued. Check this Microsoft official url: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2014/01/24/certificate-requirements-for-windows-2008-r2-and-windows-2012-remote-desktop-services/

Comment: Thanks J Modi. But are there any methods I can use for testing the current algorithm before I reissue the rdp cert?